# C# How can i deserialize json DATAS array in the simple struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

```
{
    "ASD": { "CONNECTIONS": 1, "DATAS": [0, 0, 0] },
    "Something": {
        "PITCH": 77,
    }
}    

data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DATA>(text);

public class DATA
{
    public struct ASD
    {
            public float CONNECTIONS;
            public float[] DATAS; //?? This is every time is null
    }

    public struct Something
    {
        public float PITCH;
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the code and the models that you are using to deserialize the JSON. Please add them as text to the question rather than images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not enough to simply *define* the structs you want to use. The object `ASD` must have *properties* typed as these structs. (Note the `0 references` hint above the definitions in your screenshot!)

```
public class DATA
{
    public ASD ASD{get;set;}
    public Something Something {get;set;}
}

public struct ASD
{
    public float CONNECTIONS;
    public float[] DATAS; //?? This is every time is null (not any more it wont be!)
}

public struct Something
{
    public float PITCH;
}
```

Live example of it working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wgI5zR

Comment: Yes, I did this, but the DATAS array in the ASD struct is null, 
i tried to write out the message in the console and the DATAS wasn't zero"ASD":{"CONNECTIONS":1,"DATAS":[4,23,1]}.

Comment: @Smeth Seems to work fine for me - look here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MByBMP You must be doing something else wrong

Comment: Maybe, actually everything else working fine only the Datas array return null. I will try to figure it out...